# Trying to use the selenium webdriver with Firefox to bring up a URL

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

so recently I've been trying to build a bot with the selenium webdriver, python and Firefox.
Everytime I run the script it opens up Firefox but doesn't run the url I pass into it.
I've installed the geckodriver unzipped it placed it in my python file.

Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


Class TwitterBot:
   def __init__(self, username, password):
       self.username = username
       self.password = password
       self.bot = webdriver.Firefox()

   def login(self):
     bot = self.bot
     bot.get('https://twitter.com/')
     time.sleep(3)
     email = bot.find_element_by_class_name('email-input')
     password = bot.find_element_by_name('session[password]')
     email.send_keys(self.username)
     password.send_keys(self.password)

ayo = TwitterBot('#enter username or email', '#enter password')
ayo.login
```

This is the code, I dont know what I'm doing wrong all it just does is start up Firefox and then nothing happens.

Comment: @Wonka self.bot is the variable taking in the function webdriver.Firefox() I've tried that just now threw an error

Answer (score 0):

Change your call ayo.login to ayo.login()

```
class t:
    def __init__(self, u,p):
        self.u = u
        self.p = p
        print("RUN")
    def login(self):
        print("login")

ayo = t("pp", "uu")
RUN
ayo.login
<bound method t.login of <__main__.t instance at 0x7f5d9ee44280>>
ayo.login()
login
```

Comment: silly me forgetting to add the (). Of course it's a function Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome, you were close to the solution